# Can I change the font of a pdf document that was sent to me?

Tags: fonts, pdf

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  I was sent a pdf file that I can barely read because the characters are jammed together, probably because of some font compatibility problem. I know nothing about the sending environment.  Is there some way to substitute a different font for the troublesome one so I can read the document?

Comment: Open the PDF with LibreOffice Draw select the text, right click and select Font. If the PDF was saved from a program it may be editable, if it is from a scan it probably isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be very much dependent on how the PDF was created. If it was constructed as a straight-up image of a document (which is common with PDF versions of a scanned document), then you're stuck with what you see. If this is a dynamically flowing PDF, then you can change the font with LibreOffice Draw.

It *may be* rather crude, though. Here is an example of a PDF edit through LibreOffice Draw of a PDF that I generated from a Word file on macOS a couple of years back:

[image: LibreOffice Draw]

As you can see, the editing for this PDF is line by line, and there's no accounting for the page width.

As for other tools, I've heard that Inkscape can edit PDFs, but have never tried this myself. Some people have said that Gimp will work, but this is wildly inaccurate based on every PDF I've ever opened with the application.

Comment: you can usually just zoom in and out . with gnome default document viewer, evince, it is control key down  and mouse scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gimageReader` to first extract the text from the pdf and then use it to create a new document with any format you require.

Here are the basic steps

You need to add a PPA and then install it. To do that, here’s what you need to type in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sandromani/gimagereader
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimagereader
```

It can also be downloaded from the Ubuntu Software Center

[reference](https://itsfoss.com/gimagereader-ocr/)

Answer (score 0):

### Editing Font on a PDF Using LibreOffice Draw

Open the PDF with LibreOffice Draw, select the text, right click and select Font. If the PDF was saved from a program it may be editable, if it is from a scan it probably isn't. Please see image below.

[image]